# Linq Join Data Table to Entity Framework - Not Evaluating results

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, join

I am working under Visual Studio 15 in Windows 10.1 and SQL Sever 2016.  My system processes CSV text files by importing them into a Data Table then updating a SQL table with the values obtained from the Data Table.

I am trying to use LINQ JOIN statement as follows:

```
            var books = from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
            join y in db.BookFiles.AsEnumerable()
            on
            new {printid = x.Field<string>("PrintID"), packageid = x.Field<string>("PackageID")}
            equals
            new {printid = y.PrintId, packageid = y.PackageID}
            select y; 

            foreach(var book in books) 
            {
              \\Do Something
            }
```

dt is a Data Table and db is an entity framework representation of the SQL database.  I have limited dt to only to 3 records for testing.

When the foreach statement is evaluated it just keeps on evaluating until it runs out of memory.

The solution below works, so I don't think it's a data issue:

```
        List<BookFile> books = new List<BookFile>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string printid = dr.Field<string>("PrintID");
            string packageid = dr.Field<string>("PackageID");


            var book = (from data in db.BookFiles 
            where data.PrintId == printid && data.PackageID == packageid 
            select data).Single();

            books.Add(book);
        }
        foreach(var book in books)
        {
          \\Do Something
        }
```

Am I setting up the JOIN incorrectly?  I have tried using the db first then the datatable in the join.  I have tried using a defined class for the joined fields.  Any information would be helpful.

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` call here `db.BookFiles.AsEnumerable()` is causing `BookFiles` table to be fully loaded in memory. For such scenarios, you'd better use the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Remove AsEnumerable()(it will load all table in to memory, you dont need use it before join) and add ToList()(in that moment there will be real query to database) to books in foreach, like this

```
var books = from x in dt
                        join y in db.BookFiles
                        on
                        new { printid = x.Field<string>("PrintID"), packageid = x.Field<string>("PackageID") }
                        equals
                        new { printid = y.PrintId, packageid = y.PackageID }
                        select y;

            foreach (var book in books.ToList())
            {
              \\Do Something
            }
```

Comment: When I try to use the System.Data.Datable dt without the enurmerable Visual Studio will produce "could not find an implementation for the query pattern for source type 'DataTable'.'Join' not found"

If I use the dt.AsEnumerable and the db.Bookfiles without the .AsEnumerable I get the same result.  dt contains only 3 rows so it should not be a memory drain.